# View more than a week at a time in Calendar

Tags: calendar, ical

At one point in the past I learned a command line that allowed Calendar to display more than one week at a time. My preference was 2 weeks as I have a large screen iMac and like to plan out my events and tasks across two weeks. I've since lost whatever the code was due to upgrades of iOS etc. I am now running Monterey and would really like to see across more than one week at a time. Any one know a simple default command line directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have access to Mojave for testing but the command:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal n\ days\ of\ week 14
```

gets Calendar to show a two week view. From [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7502126).

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great! And I am using Monterey.